# Open predefined app and insert predefined text with iPhone shortcut

Tags: iphone, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I'm almost freaking out here. Since hours (!!!) I'm trying to create a simple shortcut with Apples Shortcut app on iPhone, but with no success.

This is what I want the shortcut to do when I start it from within the Shortcut app: Open a predefined app, e.g. Mail, and paste/insert an in the Shortcut app predefined text in the currently active/focused text field.

How can I do that? I'm able to open the app, the text field is also active/focused but no text is inserted. I tried any action called text or similar, but none of them worked.

So how can I do that?

Comment: I believe the only thing you can do is to use the shortcut to send the predefined text to the clipboard then you must manually paste the clipboard into your message.

Comment: @Allan Really? Why isn't Shortcut able so do such an easy task?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there’s no paste (probably for security reasons) and there’s no available action libraries for Mail unlike Calendar.  Why Apple chose not to include those or make them available is unclear.